# JavaScript extend date prototype requirejs module

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, prototype

How can I extend Date object in requirejs module?
for instance in case of using typical script I can write something like this:

```
Date.prototype.today = function();
```

then I can just import this script and use this new extension function for any Date obj:

```
new Date().today();
```

Any idea how to make it possible using requirejs define()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found a solution:
'dateExtension.js'

```
define(function(){ 
    Date.prototype.today = function(){}; 
    return Date;
})
```

and then it can be used like so:

```
define(['dateExtension'], function(DateExtension){new DateExtension().today()})
```

Comment: You're still modifying the global `Date` prototype when you do this.

Comment: @idbehold Yep, that was my goal. Do you know another way to achieve that?

Comment: Oh, no I just didn't know that was your intention. Carry on.